# PRISM: Nested regions in a region

Tags: c#, wpf, module, prism, region

The project is based on PRISM.

I've got a main region in the `TabControl` in the Shell.

```
        <!-- Main Region : A tab control -->
        <TabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" >
        </TabControl>
```

Then, I've got several `Modules` where all of them contains the same views. And must be added to the tab control region.

```
|_ModuleA
| |_ViewA
|
|_ModuleB
  |_ViewB
```

Check please the image. In tab `ModuleA`, it shows in the left of the tab content `ViewA`, and the right is a generic view because all the tabs must show the same UI.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Why does the common view on the right have to be in the tab control region? Why not make a separate region inside your shell but outside the tab control region?

Comment: Because in the real application, when select an item in ViewA, it will show the item details in the common View. I mean, each module will maintain the item details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess 'lecrank' already answered the question. There's no problem to add Region inside other Region or View. What I did in my project:

- Every Module receive a copy of IRegionManager and IEventAggregator objects in constructor (I use MEF)
- In `Initialize()` function every Module register it own Regions with it own View, etc, etc...
- Whenever event or program flow should be passed to another Module (for example) then I just .Publish() predefined event (CompositePresentationEvent) with parameters.
- The Shell itslef it's just empty template that defined just couple 'global' Regions (like TabControl in your scenario) and everything that displayed on it is coming from different Modules Views and not implemented in Shell class or even in Shell containing project.

So feel free to define and implement Regions and Views in another modules - just pass somehow the IRegionManager and IEventAggregator instances into Module class.

Comment: Can you show me this situation but using UNITY CONTAINER? I forgot mention it!

I'm registring my views, but it throws me error because the regions has already exist

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit odd, but if i'm not mistaken u should look for 'composite presenters'. A presenter that registers a new region to the regionmanager where other views can be shown. U can make a region locally scoped as well. For some more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx

And a good place to find answers for Prism is on the compositewpf codeplex site, someone asking perhaps the same question: http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/273120

Comment: The MSDN magazine no longer works.  Can you tell me which issue you found the article in?

Comment: my answer was from 6 years ago and never market as answer anyway.

Comment: Ehm, well I'll trade an upvote for the issue, if you still know which one it is.  A Google Search for "composite presenters MSDN magazine" didn't yield much.

Comment: This might be the update link to the dead Composite WPF Codeplex link: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/37164/introduction-to-composite-wpf-cal-prism-part-1